# If a query cannot be folded, then does it fetch the entire table?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

When a query can be folded - that is - when the last step of the power query transformations shows the native SQL query, then Power BI will only pull specific columns from the SQL table.

If a query cannot be folded, and say one of the prior transformations is to remove all columns other than orderid, date, saleamt; then does Power BI fetch the entire table (all columns)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PQ streams data. If folding cannot occur, then each row is streamed as required. You can learn everything you want to know from Ben Gribaudo: https://bengribaudo.com/blog/2020/08/26/5417/how-power-query-thinks

PQ may also reorder your steps to optimise folding.

Comment: So if the last step isn't able to fold then it will still try to fold previous step?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The video is a good watch to learn the details.

Comment: Any other questions on this one?

Comment: So is there any way I can find until which step the Power query is able to fold.

Comment: Not easily in PowerBI Desktop at the moment. It may appear a step doesn't fold when in fact it does. The online editor is much more accurate and clear on which steps do indeed fold. If you are doing this in PBI Desktop, you can right click the last step which says "show native query" and examine the SQL or turn on performance analyser to see what is being sent to your DB. Here is a link to the online indicators and even there there is still a "might fold". https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/step-folding-indicators